# Image upsampling using interpolation function in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, interpolation, image-resizing

TensorFlow now provides [a function for trilinear interpolation](https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics/api_docs/python/tfg/math/interpolation/trilinear/interpolate). However, how can we use it to upsample a 3D image ? For example, I have an image `x` of shape `(W,H,D)` and I would like to upsample it to `(W*2,H*2,D*2)`.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi vincent59, You can use the tf.raw_ops.TrilinearInterpolation function in TensorFlow to upsample a 3D image. This function performs trilinear interpolation, which is a method for interpolating values within a cube. To achieve the upsampling, you'll need to create a new grid of coordinates for the output image, and then use TrilinearInterpolation to compute the interpolated values at these coordinates.